# Data are not passed between ViewControllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I need to pass a data between two view controllers.here is my code.

for first view controller

```
-(void)editBotton {

    Carttable *second=[[Carttable alloc]init];

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:second];
    nav.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];

    NSString *temp=titlela.text;//titlela is UILabel

    NSLog(@"%@",temp);
    self.cart=second;
    cart.cnftitle=temp;
}
```

in my cartable view controller.h

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *cnftitle;
```

and i synthesized too

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"%@",cnftitle);
}
```

one NSlog prints my text in label where another prints as NULL....

am i missing anything?

Comment: the view is loaded and value is printed right when you first push the view controller onto the stack. You are setting the value after that. The problem is just where your NSLog is. If you set the string value before you push the view controller onto the stack, it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're assigning the value after the view has loaded.

Move your assignment before the `pushViewController:`(as that's the point where the view is loaded)

Answer (score 1):

Check this code,

```
-(void)editBotton {

    Carttable *second=[[Carttable alloc]init];
    [second.view setAlpha:1.0f];

    second.cnftitle = titlea.text;

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:second];
    nav.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Enjoy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    ****in xode 4.5.1**  storyboard**
      we assume wee want to passed data between  
    viewcontroller1 to viewcontroller2
    in the viewcontroller1 in .h class we import viewcontroller2.h
    then we declare variable in viewcontroller2 ex: Nsstring *data;
    then we can passed data like this..
    in the viewcontroller1 we can code like this(in button event)

        ViewController3 *vc3=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];

       vc3.data=textfield1.text;
        vc3.image=imageview.image;
        [self presentViewController:vc3 animated:YES completion:nil];

note=set the storyboard id of viewcontroller2 as ViewController2
        it is on the right hand side utility menu 3rd tab
(select viewcontroller2 and set storyboard id)
```